# Не отображается превью кода на GitLab

Tags: gitlab

**Проблема:** при загрузке файлов в репозиторий(GitLab), GitLab не отображает cpp файлы в окошке с кодом, а просто предлагает их скачать.

У товарищей всё нормально, cpp отображается именно в окошке с кодом.

В чём может быть проблема и каковы пути её решения?

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте явно указать CPP файлы как текстовые. Добавьте следующую строку в [`.gitattributes`](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes#_generating_diff_text):

```
.cpp diff
```

и залейте изменения в gitlab.

Возможно, CPP файлы сохранены в кодировке, которую Gitlab не может распознать.